# Why do some functions open in the read-only mode in RStudio?

Tags: r, function, debugging, rstudio

I am debugging my scripts in RStudio and came across a strange behaviour. For all my working functions, when I Command + click (ctrl + click), I get to the script of that functions.

However, for my one function when I do that it opens only read only mode. Does that mean the function is buggy? How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the function was loaded: when you source the whole file, RStudio associates the function with its source file, and can jump to its definition. If, by contrast, you’ve loaded the function by e.g. only executing a single code fragment, RStudio doesn’t know which source file the function is associated with.

If you then subsequently want to jump to its definition, RStudio creates a temporary file which contains a *deparsed representation* of the function, not the original source. And since that file isn’t the original source but rather a temporary, RStudio marks it as read-only.